# I can`t save image to project folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code that saves image from FileUpload to folder:

```
int count = 1;
string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.FileName);
string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
string tempFileName = fileNameOnly;
while (File.Exists("~/ UploadedImages//" + tempFileName + extension))
{
tempFileName = string.Format("{0}({1})", fileNameOnly, count++);
}

FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ UploadedImages//" + tempFileName + extension));
```

Comment: Is that your actual code?  You have a space before UploadedImages.

Comment: Please provide the exception details. Use the [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to complete your question.

Comment: Maybe [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx) could be useful here

Comment: @SeanO'Neil Lol ty I didn`t notice that :D
btw do you know why the image isn`t saving to folder and inserted into my database without the counter add?

Answer (score -2):

```
string ext = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
if (ext.ToLower() == ".jpg" || ext.ToLower() == ".png" || ext.ToLower() == ".gif" || ext.ToLower() == ".ico")
{
        string fn = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/assets/image/"),fn));
}
if (ext.ToLower() == ".pdf")
{
    string fn = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/assets/pdf/"), fn));
}
if (ext.ToLower() == ".doc" || ext.ToLower() == ".docx")
{
    string fn = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/assets/doc/"), fn));
}
if (ext.ToLower() == ".xls" || ext.ToLower() == ".xlsx")
{
    string fn = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/assets/excel/"), fn));
}
```